# Missed a } and/or ) on if/else

Tags: android, eclipse, if-statement

I missed a } and/or ) at the end of the code, I tried so many times but I didn't get it, can someone know?

```
        doclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;      
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));  
              startActivity(intent);     
              }  
            else{  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);   
    }
};
```

---

Edited

I added it all, I hope it do anything good for me! ........................................

```
package com.example.a;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button dadclink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

        public void addListenerOnButton() {
        dadclink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dadclink);

dadclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;      
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));  
              startActivity(intent);     
             }  
            else{  
              String natgeo= "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);   
            }
       )}; 

    } 
}
```

---

### Edited

```
package com.example.a;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button dadclink;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dadclink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dadclink);
    dadclink.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
}

private View.OnClickListener myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    private String uri;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.dadclink:
            if(!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;      
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));  
              startActivity(intent);     
            }  
            else{  
              String natgeo= "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);   
            }
           break;
        }
   } 

};

}
```

---

### Edited for full

active_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textStyle="italic" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dadclink"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="blah blah"
            android:textSize="38sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.a;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button dadclink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dadclink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dadclink);
        dadclink.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        private String uri;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.dadclink:
                if (!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {
                    String natgeo = "natgeo";
                    String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                } else {
                    String natgeo = "natgeo";
                    String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    };

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.a"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

### Edited

```
package com.example.a;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button dadclink;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dadclink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dadclink);
        dadclink.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
    }
    private View.OnClickListener myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() { 
        final String uri = null;
         @Override 
         public void onClick(View v) { 
             switch(v.getId()){ 
             case R.id.dadclink: 
                 String natgeo= "natgeo"; 
                 String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo; 
                 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)); 
                 startActivity(i); break;       
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You didn't close your **else**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
doclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;      
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));  
              startActivity(intent);     
              }  
            else{  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);   
            }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

you can implement OnClickListener like below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button dadclink;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dadclink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dadclink);
    dadclink.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
}

private View.OnClickListener myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.dadclink:
            if(!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;      
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));  
              startActivity(intent);     
            }  
            else{  
              String natgeo= "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);   
            }
           break;
        }
   } 

};

}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
private View.OnClickListener myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    final String uri = null;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.dadclink:
              String natgeo= "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);
           break;
        }
   } 

};
```

and remember added this line to your `manifest.xml` file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
 ....
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
 ...
</activity>
```

Comment: Update .. :) I'm lost! there are many things to update, like eclipse and I didn't do it yet! For a reason!

Comment: I'll check what you added, give me time

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, I added the full program..

Comment: @Sohar Do you see any logcat error? Why you check `uri.contains()` ? Does works with my update2 code? remove `if/else` condition and use from `else` block code for test.

Comment: Sorry Naruto, can you please paste the entire code?

Comment: @Sohar copy this lines in `onClick` event for testing your code: `String natgeo= "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);`

Comment: I did change it, no error but it's the same problem which says (Unfortunately, A has stopped) can you please paste the entire code?

Comment: @Sohar maybe problem is another issue. Do you see any logcat error after  (Unfortunately, A has stopped) occured?  `private View.OnClickListener myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    final String uri = null;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.dadclink:
              String natgeo= "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);
           break;
        }
   } 

};`

Comment: I edited at the first post, there is warning "final String uri = null;" there is a yellow line underneath uri .. the logCat is at the next post

Comment: [DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[Logcat] device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:774)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:396)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:347) at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:593)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPanel.java:531)

Comment: The thing is, I want to run natgeo on facebook application, if the application isn't there; it runs it at the browser.

Comment: Now it only runs it in the browser

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61686/discussion-on-answer-by-naruto-uzumaki-missed-a-and-or-on-if-else).

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an anonymous inner class, your last line -

```
    startActivity(i);   
  }
};
```

Should be

```
    startActivity(i);   
  }
}); // <-- close the open paren.
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment, I recommend you extract it to a class -

```
class MyListener extends OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    String natgeo = "natgeo";          
    String uri = (!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) ?
         "fb://Page/" : "https://www.facebook.com/";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri+natgeo));
    startActivity(intent);     
  }
}
```

Then

```
doclink.setOnClickListener(new MyListener());
```

Comment: I got more confused :) I'll edit my post and add the entire code, I hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 0):

```
doclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {
                    String natgeo = "natgeo";
                    String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(uri));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    String natgeo = "natgeo";
                    String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Same thing, it didn't work!